# Unable to view revision history of an Area 51 proposal

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, revisions-list, 500-server-error

I'm trying to view the revision history of a proposal on Area 51 by clicking the "edited by X Y days ago", but whenever I click on it, it brings me to this error page:

[image]

[Here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/error)'s a link to the error page.

I've tested it on all proposals I'm following/committed to, and all of them bring me to the error page.

For reference, I'm using Chrome on Windows 10.

**Edit:** upon further testing, this only happens on proposals in the definition or commitment phase. It works as expected for sites in the beta or launched phase. You should be able to reproduce it with any of the proposals [here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=progress) that have been edited. Here's one random example: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/121498/transport-planning.

Comment: Ah - this is probably an Area51 feature. It doesn't work like the rest of SE :-)

Comment: It failed for me also on a proposal I haven’t committed to/followed.

Comment: This was [reposted on Area 51 Discussions](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29682/why-cant-i-see-the-revision-history-of-a-proposal), where an employee has marked it [tag:status-review].

Comment: @Sonic lol...... (marking as review is a sad joke in that case.)

Answer (score 5):

This has been fixed, and the revision in question (and any others that had the same issue) should now load.

> the revision page
> for area 51
> should now load just fine