# Error when trying to see a revision of a proposal of Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, revisions-list, specific-proposal

When I try to see  a revision of a proposal of Area 51:

[image]

(I click on the "4 days ago")

It shows me the error page:

[image]

Here's a raw link for anyone who would like to try it:
https://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/126416/revisions

So, is this a bug?

Comment: [Already reported](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29682) on Area 51 meta and [here as well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321537).